# Remove non-duplicated entries

Tags: python, pandas

A dataframe (pandas) has two columns. It is required to remove those rows for which the entry in 1st column has no duplicates.

Example data:

1 A 
1 B
  2 A
  3 D
  2 C
  4 E
 4 E

Expected output

1 A 
1 B
  2 A
   2 C
  4 E
 4 E

In other words, it is required to remove all single-occuring (implies unique) values from 1st column. What would be fastest way to achieve this in python (~50k rows)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use duplicated() method

`df.duplicated('c1')` default flags all but first, and `take_last=True` gives the others.

```
In [600]: df[df.duplicated('c1') | df.duplicated('c1', take_last=True)]
Out[600]:
   c1 c2
0   1  A
1   1  B
2   2  A
4   2  C
5   4  E
6   4  E
```

Comment: In newer versions of pandas one has to use `keep='last'` instead of `take_last=True`.

Comment: Relatively new to pandas here: If i understand this correctly, this is meant to select all columns marked as true by the duplicates method. And you use the `or` symbol to make sure you don't drop either the first or last occurence of each duplicate, right?

So in the most current version of pandas, wouldn't it make most sense to just use ```df[df.duplicated('c1', keep=False)]```?

from the docs:
```False : Mark all duplicates as True.```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way: Assume the dataframe is 'd' and the columns are named 'a' and 'b'. First, get the number of times each unique value in 'a' appears:

```
e = d['a'].value_counts()
```

Then get the list of values greater than 1, and return the rows whose first column is a member of that list:

```
d[d['a'].isin(e[e>1].index)]
```